# ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rstan’ on CentOS 7

Tags: r, centos7

I am using R 3.6.0 on CentOS 7.8.2003.

I went through the following steps to install rstan.

1. sudo yum install libv8-dev
2. sudo yum install libv8
3. Make directory ~/.R and file ~/.R/Makevars
4. Edit ~/.R/Makevars
5. Add the following

   CXX14 = g++ -fPIC

   CXX14FLAGS = -O3

   CXX14PICFLAGS = -fpic

   CXX14STD = -std=gnu++1y
6. Update gcc as described [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-centos-7/).
7. In R: Sys.setenv( TZ="Etc/GMT-4" )
8. In R: install.packages("rstan")

Ends with

```
ar -rs ../inst/lib//libStanServices.a stan_fit.o stan_fit_base.o
ar: creating ../inst/lib//libStanServices.a
installing to /home/peter/R/00LOCK-rstan/00new/rstan/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘loo’ 2.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 2.3.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rstan’
* removing ‘/home/peter/R/rstan’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpZa6XF1/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rstan") :
  installation of package ‘rstan’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I would look at `namespace ‘loo’ 2.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 2.3.0 is required`. Which version do you have installed? Try to update it separately if you have < 2.3.0

Comment: You're right.  install.packages("loo",version="2.3.0")   in R fixed the problem.  Thanks very much,

Comment: Otago,  now that the problem's solved, please either delete the question or post the solution as an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by entering the following command in R.

```
install.packages("loo",version="2.3.0")
```

Rerunning

```
install.packages("rstan")
```

then ran successfully to completion.